# android-apt doesn't find AndroidManifest.xml although it exists

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Using the following `apt` configuration android-apt doesn't find the manifest file although it exists at the claimed path.

```
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs.processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.test'
        logLevel "TRACE"
        logConsoleAppender true
    }

}
```

When running the build, gradle states:

```
error: Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file in specified path : [/Users/lars.blumberg/coding/test/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml]
```

Though, the file exist at the given location.

If I however hard code the manifest path, thus changing the configuration to the following:

```
        androidManifestFile '/Users/lars.blumberg/coding/test/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
```

the build succeeds. What's going wrong here?

Comment: [http://www.wenda.io/questions/4107186/manifest-mergeing-android-studio-0-8-1-upgrade-build-error-property-manifest.html](http://www.wenda.io/questions/4107186/manifest-mergeing-android-studio-0-8-1-upgrade-build-error-property-manifest.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt I need to add `[0]` to `outputs`. It then reads:

```
androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
```

and leads to a successful build.